# Tricky problem of infinite harmonic sum of polynomials

Tags: polynomials

Let A be the set of all polynomials f with *positive integral* coefficients such that $f(n)|(2^n-1)$ for all $A\in\mathbb{N}$. Then $$\sum_{f\in A} {1\over f(2019)}=?$$

I tried to define a polynomial, but where is the degree? Hence I considered all polynomials that leave remainder $1$ mod $f.$ Hence $2^n-1$ is divisible. But actually I cannot guess how to proceed! Please help!

Comment: What is the source of all the questions you are asking?

Comment: My unsolved problems in todays exam

Comment: Do you mean ... Let $A$ be the set of all polynomials $f$ with *positive integral* coefficients such that $f(n)|(2^n-1)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then $$\sum_{f\in A} \frac{1}{f(2019)}=\text{?}$$ (Note that, along with formatting, I replaced "for all $A\in\mathbb{N}$" with "for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$".)

Comment: Yes! But i could not type it so replaced it

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your questions.  You can take a look at how I edited your post, to begin with.

Comment: Can someone help please?

Comment: Let us start by trying to understand the set $A$ better. According to the conditions on  $f$ we must have $f(1) = 1$ (take $n=1$ and use that $f$ has positive coefficents). But since $f$ has positive, integral coefficients, this seems to indicate that $f$ must have the form $f(x) = x^k$. But in order for an $f$ on this form to meet the condition we would have to have that $k$ should divide $2^k -1$ for all $k$, which is clearly not true. So I suspect $A$ is empty, hence the sum is 0.

Comment: @Testcase: Don't forget $f(x)\equiv 1$. (BTW: You can eliminate the possibility of $f(x)=x^k$ for $k\geq 1$ by simply noting that $2^k \not\mid 2^2-1$.)